# SQL Azure Premium tier is unavailable for more than a minute at a time and we're around 10-20% utilization, if that

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We run a web service that gets 6k+ requests per minute during peak hours and about 3k requests per minute during off hours. Lots of data feeds compiled from 3rd party web services and custom generated images. Our service and code is mature, we've been running this for years. A lot of work by good developers has gone into our service's code base.

We're migrating to Azure, and we're seeing some serious problems. For one, we are seeing our Premium P1 SQL Azure database routinely become unavailable for 1-2 full entire minutes. I'm sorry, but this seems absurd. How are we supposed to run a web service with requests waiting 2 minutes for access to our database? This is occurring several times a day. It occurs less after switching from Standard level to Premium level, but we're nowhere near our DB's DTU capacity and we're getting throttled hard far too often.

Our SQL Azure DB is Premium P1 and our load according to the new Azure portal is usually under 20% with a couple spikes each hour reaching 50-75%. Of course, we can't even trust Azure's portal metrics. The old portal gives us no data for our SQL, and the new portal is very obviously wrong at times (our DB was not down for 1/2 an hour, like the graph suggests, but it was down for more than 2 full minutes):

[image: SQL Azure utilization]

[image: response times]

Azure reports the size of our DB at a little over 12GB (in our own SQL Server installation, the DB is under 1GB - that's another of many questions, why is it reported as 12GB on Azure?). We've done plenty of tuning over the years and have good indices.

Our service runs on two D4 cloud service instances. Our DB libraries are all implementing retry logic, waiting 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and then 48 seconds before failing completely. Controllers are all async, most of our various external service calls are async. DB access is still largely synchronous but our heaviest queries are async. We heavily utilize in-memory and Redis caching. The most frequent use of our DB is 1-3 records inserted for each request (those tables are queried only once every 10 minutes to check error levels).

Aside from batching up those request logging inserts, there's really not much more give in our application's db access code. We're nowhere near our DTU allocation on this database, and the server our DB is on has like 2000 DTU's available to be allocated still. If we have to live with 1+ minute periods of unavailability every day, we're going to abandon Azure.

Is this the best we get?

Querying stats in the database seems to show we are nowhere near our resource limits. Also, on premium tier we should be guaranteed our DTU level second-by-second. But, again, we go more than an entire solid minute without being able to get a database connection. What is going on?

[image: db stats]

I can also say that after we experience one of these longer delays, our stats seem to reset. The above image was a couple minutes before a 1 min+ delay and this is a couple minutes after:

[image: stats reset]

Comment: Contact support, not some web forum. This is a serious issue they will want to know about. I'd also suggest creating some kind of proof. Make a script to insert one row per second to a logging table. If you find hickups in that logging table (e.g. a minute without activity) there's clear proof that your app was not at fault.

Comment: @usr Only billing support appears available without a paid support plan. Microsoft themselves directs users to StackOverflow for Azure support: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/

Comment: P1 database has 200 concurrent requests limit. Are you not hitting this limit?

Comment: @pauliusnrk The exceptions being thrown do not indicate that we are hitting the request limit. Also, Azure technical staff has confirmed this is a bug in their platform.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rant about the availability of a hosted service, not an actual question that can be answered here. Only Microsoft can address your concerns.

Comment: I'm curious to know if this downtime could have been avoided if a second instance was in use - I realize this costs more (youd have to pay for two P1's), but just wondering if you had a second instance in another region that if the downtime could have been avoided.  Can someone from MSFT/Azure team comment on this?

Comment: @DanSmith That's not a very viable option. You cannot write to a secondary DB instance. It has to be promoted to primary, and iirc that can only occur once Microsoft has ok'd a region to do so (requires a major failure on the datacenter level, and again iirc the window for them to do that was a couple hours). Failover to a secondary would have to be handled manually - you'd have to update your connection string or build your app to handle it for you. Multiple instances don't increase your reliability, with the exception of datacenter level failures (or like websites where you need at least 2).

Answer (score 2):

We have been in contact with Azure's technical staff and they confirm this is a bug in their platform that is causing our database to go through failover multiple times a day. They stated they will be deploying fixes starting this week and continuing over the next month.

Frankly, we're having trouble understanding how anyone can reliably run a web service on Azure. Our pool of Websites randomly goes down for a few minutes a few times a month, taking our public sites down. If our cloud service returns too many 500 responses something in front of it is cutting off all traffic and returning 502's (totally undocumented behavior as far as we can tell). SQL Azure has very limited performance and obviously isn't ready for prime time.