# SQL Azure resource_stats view is empty

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We're [having trouble with the reliability of our SQL Azure database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083219/sql-azure-is-unavailable-for-more-than-a-minute-at-a-time), and in an effort to see if we are consuming excessive resources I tried to view our stats records. [MSDN offers some initial guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369873.aspx) on querying sys.resource_stats

Our sys.resource_stats view returns no records at all.

[image: no stats in view]

If I try to view the monitoring in the Azure portal, I get an error that the server could not retrieve metrics.

[image: no stats in portal]

We have no idea why this view would not return any records or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is known issue that causes this telemetry not to be displayed. A fix for this issue is beeing roll-out.

You can query the [sys.dm_db_resource_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn800981.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the database itself (not master) to get the utilization data for the last hour. This view also has the advantage of showing finer granular data than sys.dresource_stats in master.

Comment: It seems the records in this table are resetting every time we get a long (1 min+) period of database unavailability. We also appear to be routinely under 10% on all metrics, yet our database connections fail for 1-2 minutes straight several times every day.

Comment: Perhaps you would take a moment to view my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083219/sql-azure-is-unavailable-for-more-than-a-minute-at-a-time/29088491#29088491. 

We appear to be nowhere near our resource limits yet our database connections fail for 1-2 minutes straight - not a single connection can be made - several times every day on the Premium tier, which has a second-by-second performance guarantee.

Comment: sys.dm_db_resource_stats will unfortunately be reset when a DB failover happens. What you are experiencing w.r.t. failovers is definitely a system issue and should not happen with this frequency. My apologies that this didn't get the right level of attention yet. Can you please send me an email to my username (dot in the middle) @microsoft.com with your subscription id, server name and DB name? I will hand this off directly to engineering for investigation.

Comment: Hi @JanEngelsberg. Was this problem ever fixed? Is there any workaround that you could add to this answer to keep it updated? Thanks!